# Display Image in Horizontal UL LI with Sprite in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

[Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp), by themselves, are not evil; however, trying to get these to work in an [unordered list](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/bulletlists.html) is difficult. Going a step further and trying to get this `unordered list` to display **horizontally** (working example [>> HERE <<](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal)) is certainly an enigma.

Here is my jsFiddle Project: [jsFiddle: hNJmD](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/hNJmD/)

It seems like every time I get something working, I make the smallest edit to customize it for my app and it breaks.

- **Does it matter what order items in a CSS file are declared?**
- Does a `<ul>` tag have to be defined before a `<li>` tag?
- Does `height:` need to be specified before `width:`? (I generally try to list things alphabetically so I don't accidentally have duplicates)

Here is the image I am using as my Sprite:

[image: Sprite]

**My Goal:**

- Center the menu horizontally the page
- Have the full image display (all 50 px)
- Disable the `a.hover` effect for the **active** item (*Link 1*)

The CSS is:

```
#nav {
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 8px #696969;
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#nav ul {
  list-style-type:none; /* removes the bullet from the list */
}
#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 192px;    
}
#nav a {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Sp7jc.gif') 0 -100px no-repeat;
  display: block;
  color:Blue;
}
#nav a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -50px;
  color:Red;
}
#nav .active, a:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;        
  color:Black;
}
#nav span {
  top: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
​
```

The HTML used in the jsFiddle is repeated here as well:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <ul id="nav">
      <li>
        <a class="active" href="#">
          <span>Link 1</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Link 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Link 3</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <p>REFERENCE: Sprite (Width: 192, Height: 150):</p>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Sp7jc.gif">
</div>
</body>​
```

**Can somebody show me how to get this crazy thing to work?**

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hNJmD/1/ ?

Comment: yeah! Gawd! Why is this so hard?

Comment: I'll post an answer and an explanation.

Comment: ie7 doesn't like it when you have an LI without a UL.

Comment: UniAvenger - are you referring to the CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to look like this: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hNJmD/1)**, then this is what I did:

- Combined your `#nav` and `#nav ul` rules since they refer to the same thing.
- To that rule I added `margin:0 auto;` and `width:600px;` which centers the items
- Then on `#nav a` I added `display: block;` and `height:50px;` which allows the links to take up the proper amount of height.
- Finally I added a rule, `#nav .active:hover` that only affects the active element so it doesn't appear to change.

And to answer one of your questions about whether the order of CSS rules matters, the answer is yes and no. With respect to width and height in a rule, the order is irrelevant, but the order the rules appear in can matter, as does the specificity of the rule.

Comment: OK, a few comments. 1) `vertical-align: middle;` appears to do **nothing**. The text does not center in the 50px tall image area. [UniAvenger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520737/display-image-in-horizontal-ul-li-with-sprite-in-css#comment16855223_12520737) said IE7 does not like LI w/o UL, so I tried this in my IE9 (instead of Chrome) and my images don't show at all until I added the `alt` tag.

Comment: Well vertical-align is only valid for inline level elements, not block level. And yes, LI elements without a UL (or OL) parent aren't valid.